# JQuery, add table row without declaring the tags in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to prepare a table row  as a template in a HTML doc in order for not typing it in JS as what I've done mostly. I just saved the DOM element as JQuery object and cloned but doing it in a  element seems it doesn't saved as an object.

I'm avoiding declaring in JS:

```
var _row = '<tr><td></td></tr>';
```

Since I wanted to make the  element as dynamic by JS rather than declaring it as a string so I'm trying to create a HTML template for a table row.

In HTML:

```
<tr id='sampleRow'></tr>
```

In JS:

```
var _row = $('#sampleRow');
```

When consoling log the _row will give a result of *init* rather than an object.

How can I possibly accomplish like this?

In HTML:

```
<div class='sampleDiv'></div>
```

In JS:

```
var _container = $('.sampleDiv').clone();
```

In which it is an object.

Comment: You're getting `init` object because there may not be any `DOM` element associated with that selector.

Comment: @NishanthMatha I just solved it though. My mistake first is declaring a <tr> element in which can't be hidden and tried to contain it inside a <div> but still I don't get my desired output but It should be inside of another <table> rather.

Answer (score 1):

I just found my solution,

Instead of using  as the container for table row template in which when you call it via JQuery and clone it and append to a table nothing happens, I used a table as the container.

In HTML:

```
<table class="destTable">
</table>

<table class="tableRowTmp" hidden>
    <tr><td colspan="6">Sample</td></tr>
</table>
```

In JS:

```
var oBannerTable = $('.destTable');
var oRow = $('.tableRowTmp').find('tr').clone();

oBannerTable.append(oRow.show());
```

Comment: If you have difficulty appending `<tr>` to a `<table>`, try appending to `<tbody>`. Even if a `<table>` is in markup, without a `<tbody>`, browsers by default will append a `<tbody>` to `<table>` by default.

Comment: Actually I used <tbody>, I just mentioned <table> because it is the one that is common but thanks for mentioning it for other users. :)

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer declaring simple objects like that in javascript through jQuery like this

```
$("<tr />", {  text: 'Table Row txt',
               class: 'some class',
               id: 'elementid'
             }).appendTo("tbody");
```

If you want to add elements to that tr you can chain it and use append as well which looks like

```
$("<tr />", {  text: 'Table Row txt',
               class: 'some class',
               id: 'elementid'
             }).append($('<div />', {
               text: 'Some text inside the div',
               class: 'anotherclass'
             })).appendTo("tbody");
```

Which would make

```
<tr class='some class' id='elementid'>Table Row txt
  <div class='anotherclass'>Some Text inside the div</div> 
<tr/>
```

If you want to use html as a template I would instead suggest using a method like John Resig suggests

http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

So you can do

```
<script type='companyname/mytemplate' id='trTemplate'>
 <tr id='sampleRow'></tr>
</script>

var template = $($("#trTemplate").innerHtml());
```